# Why does a function with generic argument break Typescript inferrance

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a React Component that extracts and extends the props of a Component passed in via an `as={Component}` argument. Example below

```js
type ComponentWithAs = <Props>(props: Props & {
  as: React.ComponentType<Props>
}) => any;

let TestWithAs: ComponentWithAs = () => null;
```

This works as such:

```js
type Props = {
    value: string;
    options: string[];
    genericFunc: (test: string) => void;
};
function Comp(props: Props) { return null };

TestWithAs({
    as: Comp,
    value: "",
    options: [""],
    genericFunc: (test) => {}, // works
})
```

However when passing generic components that use those generics in functions. It just infers unkown for the generic.

```js
type GenericProps<T> = {
    value: T;
    options: T[];
    genericFunc: (test: T) => void;
};
function GenericComp<T>(props: GenericProps<T>) { return null };

TestWithAs({
    as: GenericComp, // does not infer generic
    value: "",
    options: [""],
    genericFunc: (test: string) => {}, // should work but infer's unkown
})
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=3&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgGFdIA7JFmAdWBgAsBBAM5wAvHAA8ABRxhBAPgAUYGYIBccaRFlwAZHADecFGsTEYAOibgIbDgBVaSKSrlwAvgEpRrlC2oUAGyR4OyRBLh4BEytWdgi+IVE4BS8RVxYAVwCAiipHOABxdiQoYDRNWXE7VzF9cjgGuAA3FACMpHU7Cka4LRhgGxM7AG0AXW7GgHNi0rQAMQyWNHUFGDCYTtTXJohgABMKNwpMRYwBlkKZspiqxWUtEyK2WYrBW69DIhgMqAvM7PcuVC4W4CUECjqPWM6ieJWuzAANHAAPTIuB7CBhOAsCDwYAsTAlODTZ5leqNFptDoEfAI8kNPrnEzDfD4UZ0nokuHzU4rNbhdThUosSZbAxuJGouCCXgQLJ7bG4uAAd2gAGs6Z4gA)

For some reason all the props are inferred as `unkown`. Why does this happen and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the type and hence it gets inferred as `unknown` and doesn't line up as expected.

You must specify the type properly for it to adhere to the generic type that you have set. Something like this,

```
TestWithAs<GenericProps<string>>({
    as: GenericComp,
    value: "",
    options: [""],
    genericFunc: (test: string) => {}
})
```

Comment: I understand that it will work by passing explicit type, however I was asking why it is required when a function is passed in but not when I remove the `genericFunc` 

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgGFdIA7JFmAdWBgAsBBAM5wAvHAA8ABRxhBAPgAUYGYIBccaRFlwAZHADecFGsTEYAOibgIbDgBVaSKSrlwAvgEpRrlC2oUAGyR4OyRBLh4BEytWdgi+IVE4BS8RVxYAVwCAiipHOABxdiQoYDRNWXE7VzF9cjgGuAA3FACMpHU7Cka4LRhgGxM7AG0AXQo3CkwMlgwBlkLi0rQYqsVlLRMitmWKwTWvQyIYDKgFzOz3ClDw7gTBBTqe43VtkrKYgBo4AHofuAAJhAwnAWBB4MAWJgSnAAOZLMr1RotNodAj4T5Ihp9eYmYb4fCjcieIA)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you elaborate please. From what I can tell, it cannot auto interpret things based on how you have set it up and you must specify the generic type again for it to understand the intent. But I will wait for your clarification and ensure im not missing something. May be you can edit the question to add a use case of this works vs this does not work vs what is your expectation with a simpler sample may be so we can follow along and assist accordingly.